# How to add a new class to the chromium source code? Linker won't see the new header and .cc files with the new class

Tags: c++, google-chrome, chromium

I am working on a project that deals with ungoogled-chromium. Part of my task is to change some parameters that are spread across multiple header files. The idea was to have a custom class that would load data from a config file, save it to the variables in a custom class and then update the needed parameters in different classes.

Additional info:

-I am building Chromium in release mode, not component.

-My idea was to put this class in src/base, as I want to reuse this in other classes, and I figured it should be put somewhere in the lower levels.

-I am not the best with C++

The idea works in a separate, smaller solution that I built as a test, but it fails to work properly in chromium. Here are the header and .cc files:

variables.h

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

namespace base {
    class GlobVars {
        public:
            static void updateVars();
            static int getDevMem();
        private:
            // config vars
            static int device_memory;
            static double battery_percentage;
            //static std::string user_agent, platform;
    };

} // namespace base

#endif
```

variables.cc

```
#include "variables.h"

namespace base {
    int GlobVars::device_memory = 0;
    double GlobVars::battery_percentage = 0;
    //std::string GlobVars::user_agent = "", GlobVars::platform = "";

    void GlobVars::updateVars() {
        device_memory = 456;
        battery_percentage = 0.768;
    }

    int GlobVars::getDevMem(){
        return device_memory;
    }
} // namespace base
```

And here is where I try to use the function getDevMem():

```
#include "third_party/blink/public/common/device_memory/approximated_device_memory.h"

#include "base/check_op.h"
#include "base/system/sys_info.h"
#include "base/variables.h"

namespace blink {
    // static
    float ApproximatedDeviceMemory::approximated_device_memory_gb_ = 0.0;
    int64_t ApproximatedDeviceMemory::physical_memory_mb_ = 0;
    
    // static
    float ApproximatedDeviceMemory::GetApproximatedDeviceMemory() {
      return ::base::GlobVars::getDevMem(); 
      //return approximated_device_memory_gb_;
    }
}  // namespace blink
```

Here is the specific error message I keep getting:

```
FAILED: chromedriver_unittests.exe chromedriver_unittests.exe.pdb

..\\..\\third_party\\llvm-build\\Release+Asserts\\bin\\lld-link.exe /OUT:./chromedriver_unittests.exe /nologo -libpath:..\\..\\third_party\\llvm-build\\Release+Asserts\\lib\\clang\\16.0.0\\lib\\windows "-libpath:../../../../../../../Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/ATLMFC/lib/x64" "-libpath:../../../../../../../Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/lib/x64" "-libpath:../../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/NETFXSDK/4.8/lib/um/x64" "-libpath:../../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/lib/10.0.20348.0/ucrt/x64" "-libpath:../../../../../../../Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/lib/10.0.20348.0/um/x64" /MACHINE:X64  /PDB:./chromedriver_unittests.exe.pdb @./chromedriver_unittests.exe.rsp

lld-link: error: undefined symbol: public: static int \__cdecl base::GlobVars::getDevMem(void)

\\\>\>\> referenced by ../../third_party/blink/common/device_memory/approximated_device_memory.cc

\\\>\>\>               obj/third_party/blink/common/common/approximated_device_memory.obj

\[15619/17044\] CXX obj/v8/torque_generated_definitions/js-objects-tq.obj

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I figured that just including the header file would be sufficient to access the static variables but I keep getting undefined symbol error. My first approach was to try using the extern keyword but since that is more C like, I went with class implementation, but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I had to edit BUILD.gn files in separate folders to include .h and .cc files.

Comment: Can you show all the files in your solution - the BUILD.gn files and directory structure?